# when load the page data not loaded from data base JSP mysql

Tags: jsp

I am creating simple search using JSP and MySQL. The search as two parts. When the page is loaded have to show all records. when the user type the relevant employee id should display information of employee to table. when load the page data not loaded from data base only display search the record on the search box data displayed

```
     <div class="container">
                    <div class="form-group col-12 p-0">
                     <%
                        Connection con;
                        PreparedStatement pst;
                
                        ResultSet rs;
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mcompany","root","");
                        String empid = request.getParameter("empid");
   if(request.getMethod().compareToIgnoreCase("post")==0)
        {

                        if(empid.toUpperCase().equals("ALL"))
                        {                    
                   
                        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee where id =?");
                        
                        }
                         pst.setString(1, empid);
                         rs = pst.executeQuery();
                         
                         while(rs.next())
                         {
                             out.print("<TR>");
                             out.print("<TD>" + rs.getString("name") + "<TD>");
                             out.print("<TD>" + rs.getString("phone") + "<TD>");
                             out.print("<TD>" + rs.getString("salary") + "<TD>");
                             out.print("</TR>");
                         }}
                      %>           
          <body>
                <div class="container">
                     <div class="form-group col-6 p-0">
                         <form id="form" method="post" action="index.jsp" class="form-horizontal">
                               <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                                   <label>Employee ID</label>
                        <input type="text" name="empid" class="form-control" id="empid" placeholder="Employee ID">
                                </div>
                              <div class="form-group col-md-6" align="center"> 
        
                                <Button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 80px;">Submit</Button>
                      
                                </div>
                             
                         </form>
                         
                     </div>
                 </div>   
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: And where is the stacktrace?

Comment: if(empid.toUpperCase().equals("ALL"))
            {                    
        
:                 pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee");  this line sir

Comment: That's not the stacktrace. It could be possible that empid is null.

Comment: i updated the stacktrace

Comment: And as you can see there is a null point exception. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) Checkvariable con for null

Comment: Now working but. i have problem when the form is loaded data not loaded.

Comment: does your `All` condition ever get executed ? Why not put condition like this `if(empid == null || empid.isEmpty()){` and see if that works .

Comment: sir now working . when i load the form all data should loaded. when i enter id  on the textbox relvent record only need to display.

Comment: @user3698489 Try above suggestion and let me know if you face any error

Comment: yes madam.  when i load the form all data should loaded. when i enter id on the textbox relvent record only need to display.but when load the page data not loaded from data base only display search the record on the search box data displayed

Comment: are you there i update my code please check.

Comment: Just use like this - >`if (empid == null || empid.isEmpty()) {
  pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee");}else {  pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee where id =?");  pst.setString(1, empid);}` no need to put that `if(request.getMethod().compareToIgn..` remove it .

Comment: thanks madam it is working now if(request.getMethod().compareToIgn not put show error